# Finding parameters of the Weibull distribution

Tags: r, simultaneous, weibull

I'm trying to estimate the parameters of the Weibull distribution by solving the two simultaneous equations:
F(Q1)=0.25 and F(Q3)=0.75.
Algebraically, I know the answer should be:
shape parameter a=0.8038, scale parameter b=1889
but I get wildly different answers whatever I put as my starting values p.
Why doesn't the following work please?

```
# Sample quartiles
Q1<-401
Q3<-2836.75
# function:  |F(Q1)+F(Q3)-1|   so perfect fit should = 0
f<-function(params) {
  abs(pweibull(Q1,params[1],params[2])+pweibull(Q3,params[1],params[2])-1)
}
# minimise function, using starting values a=1, b=2000
p<-c(1,2000)
estimates<-nlm(f,p); estimates
```

(I'm trying to do this in base R, no extra packages.)

Comment: `Why doesn't the following work please?` Because you postulated single (ONE) condition for two parameters (shape and scale) to fit. To get two parameters you have to use two equations/conditions: F(Q1) = 1/4, F(Q3)=3/4 (or F(Q1) = 1/4, F(Q1)+F(Q3)=1 if you wish)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60511/weibull-distribution-parameters-k-and-c-for-wind-speed-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two modifications were needed. The first was hinted at by the comment but rather than using two equations I simply used two abs() terms. But that didn't produce the accurate results until I added the `typsize`-argument:

```
f<-function(params) {
   abs(pweibull(Q1,params[1],params[2])-0.25) + abs(pweibull(Q3,params[1],params[2])-0.75)
 }

 p<-c(shape=1, scale=2000)
 estimates<-nlm(f,p, fscale=.1, typsize=c(1,1500) ); estimates
#####------
$minimum
[1] 5.548144e-07

$estimate
[1]    0.8037664 1889.4379691

$gradient
[1] -1.936062e-01  5.132625e-05

$code
[1] 2

$iterations
[1] 13
```

The `fscale` argument default didn't seem to help very much. Most of my prior efforts were returning a code of 3 which meant: "last global step failed to locate a point lower than estimate. Either estimate is an approximate local minimum of the function or steptol is too small."

Comment: That is brilliant, I'd been playing around with it for hours!  Thanks!

Comment: I think that there was scaling of the initial step size based on the fscal numbers. If this answers your question you should give it a checkmark to remove it from the unanswered questions pile.